# Does known_hosts support comments?

Tags: ssh

I find the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file a bit hard to read.

It'd help if I could add comments to it so I thought I should ask if that's possible.

Comment: What sort of comments are you hoping to add? Each line is prefixed with the host that you connected to (either IP or domain name). What more information could you possibly need?

Comment: Well, the host is an IP that's hard to remember, would the entry still work if I edited the prefix to an easier to remember string?

Comment: No. That file matches IP or hostnames to host keys. If you change it to something else, it's not going to work. Just always connect using a hostname and your problem is solved.

Comment: @EEAA FWIW, hosts at the start of the line might also be hashed, either by default viz `HashKnownHosts` or from the `-H` flag in `ssh-keyscan`, and there might be no way around it all depending on the situation.

Answer (score 35):

Yes. As the manual page for `sshd` notes:

> Each line in these files contains the following fields: markers (optional), hostnames, bits, exponent, modulus, comment.  The fields are separated by spaces.
>
> [...] **The optional comment field continues to the end of the line, and is not used.**
>
> **Lines starting with ‘#’ and empty lines are ignored as comments.**

This means that you can create comments in two ways:

```
# Comments allowed at start of line
closenet,...,192.0.2.53 1024 37 159...93 closenet.example.net
```

The whole first line is comment and the `closenet.example.net` is also comment

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this solves the problem, but you can alias the IP in your .ssh/config file with something like this

```
Host rememberme
    HostName 100.110.120.130
```

Comment: While true, this has nothing to do with the question.